# Trying to take a user input and put it into a file, but am having an issue with lists

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a college project and I am building a DnD assistant for it. I am trying to take the user's input and transfer it into a file, however, the program says that the list assignment is out of range. I do not know why as I declare the list in the function.

I am trying to take the user input and write it to a file.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import filedialog

root2=tk.Tk()

F2=Frame(root2)

F2.pack(

    ipadx=300,

    ipady=200
    )

def displayAge():

   global ageChoice

   string = ageChoice.get()

   data = string
   
   x = open('john.txt','w')
   
   x.close()
   
   x = open('john.txt','r')

   info = x.read()

   fileData = info.splitlines()

   fileData[0] = data

   x.close()

   y = open('john.txt','w')

   y.write(str(fileData))

AGES=[
       "1-10",
       "11-17",
       "18-25",
       "26-30",
       "31-35",
       "36-40",
       "41-45",
       "46+"
       ]
ageChoice = StringVar(root2)

ageChoice.set(AGES[0])

ageDisplay = OptionMenu(F2, ageChoice, *AGES)

ageDisplay.place(x=70, y=150)

enter = Button(root2,padx=10,pady=10, text= "enter", command = displayAge)

enter.pack()
```

Comment: Please do format your code properly, use the following https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: first edit question and format code - you can use Ctrl+K for this.

Comment: text `it no work...` is the most useless information. And we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details. You could show what you get in file and what you expect. And if you get error then show FULL error in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Comment: opening in write mode `open('john.txt','w')` removes all data - so it makes no sense to read data from file after opening in write mode and closing it.

Comment: @furas , i think you have removed a part of code which was necessary.

Comment: @FaraazKurawle I checked all previous versions and this is all code. `enter.pack()
` is last line of code in this question.

Comment: using `str()` to save list is not good idea - it will create string which later you will have problem convert back to list. Better use `for`-loop to write every value separatelly. OR use `"\b".join(data)` to create string with every element in new line. OR use module like `json` or `pickle` to write `list` without manuall converting to string.

Comment: @FaraazKurawle I checked all previous revisions and there is no more code - in current question you can see all code which was in previous versions.

Comment: @furas , sorry my mistake i didnt knew that too long code needs to be scrolled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Things wrong with your code:

- First you are importing tkinter using `import tkinter as tk`, but then all importing using `from tkinter import *`.
- `x = open('john.txt','w')` 'w' removes all the previous data in the file, you can use 'a' to append the data to the file.

I would suggest you to use `with` to open the files as it automatically closes the file, here's a helpful [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/)

```
with open("john.txt",'a') as file:
   file.write()
```